# Option value with PHP/MYSQL values

Tags: php, mysql, html

for some reason I'm having trouble getting output with this form.. I have a horrible feeling it's a stupid reason I'm missing, but I've been staring at this for hours trying to figure out why..

```
$pnames = $mysql_db->query('SELECT * FROM patient ORDER BY name ASC'); //normal query
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>?action=addLog" method="POST">
    <select name="pname">
    <?
    while ($p = mysql_fetch_object($pnames)) {
        echo "<option value=".$p->pid.">".$p->name."</option>";
    }
    ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit"
        value="Add Log" />
</form>
```

Could somebody please help me figure out why the select has no options? (I've literally checked it against previous code that worked, which is baffling me. I'm starting to think it's a query problem.. anyways. Thanks in advance

Comment: View Source says the same code I just posted..?

Comment: Then you have a sysadmin problem, not a coding problem.

Comment: I'm using wampserver and I have no idea what a sysadmin problem could be.. lol I just know how to program, not how to host it

Comment: Are you seriously certain that if you check `view page source` from your browser, you see the code you posted here?

Comment: http://oi46.tinypic.com/29lk5ck.jpg the sql isn't there but the php is

Comment: does your server support PHP short tag? you use <? before while loop.

Comment: yup, I've used the shorthand elsewhere and it works fine there. --edit.. tried it and that fixed it. I don't know why it suddenly stopped working I've been using shorthand forever with wampserver..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to close this one

```
"<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>?action=addLog"
```

like so

```
"<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?action=addLog'?>"
```

and make sure your `PHP` supports short tag because you use it.

```
<?
while ($p = mysql_fetch_object($pnames)) {
    echo "<option value=".$p->pid.">".$p->name."</option>";
}
?>
```

try this instead

```
<?php
while ($p = mysql_fetch_object($pnames)) {
    echo "<option value=".$p->pid.">".$p->name."</option>";
}
?>
```

Comment: And even not to use asp-style tags at all since they're removed from PHP as of version 5.4.0.

Comment: agree with @budwiser, even if you never plan to upgrade or anything. but, typing two more characters will avoid breaking the whole script for the sake of savings few miliseconds. break your habit and standardize them to specs. just a thought.